# CUDA error message : invalid configuration argument

Tags: cuda

I'm a new to CUDA.  I tried to take a simple practice to help me to get familiar to it.  I coded a little program "Finding Prime Numbers".  It almost done, but there is a problem which I cannot solve it.  I found that the maximum number which I can find is 1027.  If I input more than 1027, I will get the error message:

```
getPrimeKernel launch failed!!: invalid configuration argument
findPrimeWithCuda failed!!
```

Where should I adjust my code?  Thank you.

Here is my code:

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

cudaError_t findPrimeWithCuda(bool *c, int *a, unsigned int size);

__host__ __device__ bool checkPrime(int i)
{
    for (int m = 2; m <= i - 1; m++)
    {
        if (i%m == 0) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

__global__ void getPrimeKernel(bool *c, int *a)
{
    int i = threadIdx.x;
    c[i] = checkPrime(a[i]);
}

void cudaGetPrime(int i)
{
    i = i - 3;
    int *arr = (int *)malloc((size_t)(i * sizeof(int)));
    bool *rst = (bool *)malloc((size_t)(i * sizeof(bool)));
    for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) arr[j] = j + 3;
    cudaError_t cudaStatus = findPrimeWithCuda(rst, arr, i);
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) fprintf(stderr,"findPrimeWithCuda failed!!");
}

void w_CudaArray(int lastNum)
{
    time_t t1 = time(NULL);
    cudaGetPrime(lastNum);
    time_t t2 = time(NULL);
    printf("Time to spent : %d second\n", t2 - t1);
    cout << "Computing with CUDA to count the prime numbers ends!!" << endl << endl;
}

int main()
{
    int lastNum = 0;
    cout << "The final number which you want to find the prime numbers : ";
    cin >> lastNum;
    w_CudaArray(lastNum);
}

cudaError_t findPrimeWithCuda(bool *c, int *a, unsigned int size)
{
    int *dev_a = 0;
    bool *dev_c = false;
    cudaError_t cudaStatus;

    cudaStatus = cudaSetDevice(0);
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaSetDevice failed!!");
        goto Error;
    }

    size_t totalm, freem;
    float free_m, total_m, used_m;
    cudaMemGetInfo(&freem, &totalm);
    free_m = (size_t)freem / 1048576.0;
    total_m = (size_t)totalm / 1048576.0;
    used_m = total_m - free_m;
    cout << "Total memory = " << total_m << " MB" << endl;
    cout << "Used memory  = " << used_m << " MB" << endl;
    cout << "Free memory  = " << free_m << " MB" << endl;

    cudaStatus = cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_a, size * sizeof(int));
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaMalloc dev_a failed!!");
        goto Error;
    }

    cudaStatus = cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_c, size * sizeof(bool));
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaMalloc dev_c failed!!");
        goto Error;
    }

    cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(dev_a, a, size * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaMemcpy dev_a failed!!");
        goto Error;
    }

    getPrimeKernel<<<1, size>>>(dev_c, dev_a);

    cudaStatus = cudaGetLastError();
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "getPrimeKernel launch failed!!: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(cudaStatus));
        goto Error;
    }

    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaDeviceSynchorinze returned error code %d after launching getPrimeKernel!\n", cudaStatus);
        goto Error;
    }

    cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(c, dev_c, size * sizeof(bool), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaMemory failed!");
        goto Error;
    }

    int trueNumber = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (c[i] == false) trueNumber++;
    }

    cout << "There are " << trueNumber + 2 << " prime numbers!!" << endl;

    cudaStatus = cudaDeviceReset();
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaDeviceReset failed!!");
    }

Error:
    cudaFree(dev_c);
    cudaFree(dev_a);

    return cudaStatus;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling the kernel with `size` as the number of threads per block (see the [Programming Guide section on Kernel invocation syntax)](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#execution-configuration). But the maximum number of threads per block is limited, depending on the *Compute Capability* of the device. You probably have a device with a maximum number of 1024 threads per block. So with a larger number (1027 in your case), it will no longer work. The maximum number of threads per block, depending on the device, is listed in [this table on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA#Version_features_and_specifications).

You can query the maximum number of threads per block with [cudaDeviceGetProperties](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__DEVICE.html#group__CUDART__DEVICE_1g929dcd9a191e17b7498e7ccaa3d16350), and look at the [maxThreadsPerBlock](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/structcudaDeviceProp.html#structcudaDeviceProp_118f38f08c66c8812b1ddeb16e4bf51a4) field.

In order to handle input sizes that are larger than the number of threads per block, you need ... more blocks! This means that you have to use a larger *grid* size as well. So you'll have to compute the appropriate grid- and block size for your input, and pass these as parameters to the kernel launch.

For example, like the following:

```
int inputSize = ...; // The size of the input data
int threadsPerBlock = 256; // May be queried from the device properties
int blocksPerGrid = (inputSize + threadsPerBlock - 1) / threadsPerBlock;

callKernel<<<blocksPerGrid, threadsPerBlock>>>(...);
```

This only shows the basic idea. For details, you should refer to the CUDA Programming Guide or the available samples. For example, you also have to use the **global** thread index, and make sure that you do **not** access invalid memory regions. This can be achieved by passing the length of the input array to the kernel, and check whether you're still in the bounds:

```
__global__ void callKernel(int *array, int arrayLength) {
    // Make sure to compute the GLOBAL thread index like this:
    int i = blockDim.x*blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x
    if (i >= arrayLength) {
        return;
    }
    ....
}
```

(An aside: For practicing, anything may be fine, but I'm not sure whether prime number finding in this form is really well-suited for CUDA. You might consider having a look at the more "classic" CUDA examples, like vector addition or matrix multiplication...)

Answer (score 0):

I modified some part of my code and the problem was solved.

```
__global__ void getPrimeKernel(bool *c, int *a, int size)
{
    int i = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    if (i >= size) return;
    c[i] = checkPrime(a[i]);
}
```

and this

```
cudaDeviceProp myCUDA;
if (cudaGetDeviceProperties(&myCUDA, 0) == cudaSuccess)
{
    printf("Using device %d:\n", 0);
    printf("%s; global mem: %dB; compute v%d.%d; clock: %d kHz\n",
        myCUDA.name, (int)myCUDA.totalGlobalMem, (int)myCUDA.major,
        (int)myCUDA.minor, (int)myCUDA.clockRate);
}

int threadsPerBlock = myCUDA.maxThreadsPerBlock;
int blocksPerGrid = (size + threadsPerBlock - 1) / threadsPerBlock;
cout << "Maxium number per block = " << threadsPerBlock << endl;
cout << "Blocks per Grid = " << blocksPerGrid << endl;

getPrimeKernel<<<blocksPerGrid, threadsPerBlock>>>(dev_c, dev_a, size);
```

Now it can compute the numbers which are more than 1027.  Hope this part of code can help others who is new like me.  :)